# Adding numbers in a csv file Python code

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, sum, key

My csv file looks like this:

```
Honda   100 90  345 3453    45353 
Toyota  453 656 909 5435    534543 
Nissan  123 32  535 345     954   
Ford    543 54  345 34543   4535 
Lexus   345 545 345 3453    3453  
Bmw     345 343 353 345     353453
```

How can I add the total numbers of mile per row and connect it to the key which would be the car make.

so from the CSV I want my python code be like this

```
Honda:79734397
Toyota:2343434 . (the numbers are for demonstration and not exact)
```

also at the end how do i add up all the miles from all the car?

Comment: Check out [How to create minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv
total=[]
with open('some.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
  spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
  for row in spamreader:
    print(row[0],end=' ')
    total.append(sum(list(map(int,list(filter(None, row[1:]))))))
    print(sum(list(map(int,list(filter(None, row[1:]))))))
  print('Total: ',sum(total))
```

Use Above Code

Use this link to check output

> https://repl.it/repls/ForcefulForcefulEfficiency

Comment: How would I add up all the miles at the end for a total miles?

Answer (score 0):

This should help. Iterate over the data and use a dictionary where key is car model and the sum of values is the value.

**Demo:(I am using string(s) just to show the logic)**

```
s = """Honda 100 90 345 3453 45353 
 Toyota 453 656 909 5435 534543 
 Nissan 123 32 535 345 954 
 Ford 543 54 345 34543 4535 
 Lexus 345 545 345 3453 3453 
 Bmw 345 343 353 345 353453"""

d = {} 
for i in s.split("\n"):
    val = i.strip().split()
    if val[0] not in d:
        d[val[0]] = sum(map(int, val[1:]))    #map function to convert string to int

print d
```

**Output:**

```
{'Nissan': 1989, 'Honda': 49341, 'Toyota': 541996, 'Ford': 40020, 'Bmw': 354839, 'Lexus': 8141}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the csv file into a 2D array or list, make a python dict, and set the first element of each array in the array as the dictionary key (the car name in this case) and for the rest of the elements of each aray in the array parse it to int and call the sum function. Add it to the value of the dict.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import csv
with open('filename.csv') as f:
  final_data = [[a, sum(map(int, b))] for a, *b in csv.reader(f)]
```